# No Icon showing?

Tags: c#, icons, messagebox

In my message box instead of the exclamation icon it is only showing the icon as "warning"? Is there something simple I am missing here because it has me beyond trying to figure it out.

`MessageBox.Show  ( MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation + "Delete" + " " + >(statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "   " + "Are you sure?", "Delete" + " " + >(statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()));`

Comment: Use MessageBoxIcon.Warning in an overload next to MessageBoxButtons

Comment: Try this: `MessageBox.Show("hello", "header",
                                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);`

Comment: Mike, pick up a programming book: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

Comment: I have the current book for my program and am obv overlooking a simple error in getting this to function right but thanks for making my question seem so invalid :)

Comment: Look at the code and wonder how adding an icon to a string makes sense.

Comment: Surely I haven't seen such unusual MessageBox calling before. I relooked at tags to look whether i have come in some wrong language section. Is that code even running?

Answer (score 0):

On [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx) it says to do:

> var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
>                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
>                                    MessageBoxIcon.Question);

In your case...

> MessageBox.Show("Delete" + " " + (statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()) + " " + "Are you sure?", "Delete" + " " + statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Warning",
>                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
>                                    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

You need the overload for the method, or else it will simply output the name.
If you need to see if they say yes, You can use DialogResult

Comment: Thanks but still get this same error: Error 3 Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon' E:\MIKE OLSON\C#Homework\Arrays\Arrays\Form1.cs 46 187 Arrays

Comment: Okay If you like it and think it best fits your question, please select it as the answer by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

The [MessageBox.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx) Method has a bunch of overloads.  I think the one you are looking for is this:

```
MessageBox.Show("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete " + statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Comment: The issue seems to be is I also want the text of the item selected to show as well hence the (statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), I think this is where the error is occuring.

Comment: Error 3 Argument 4: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons' to 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon' E:\MIKE OLSON\C#Homework\Arrays\Arrays\Form1.cs 46 187 Arrays

Comment: I added the text to my answer.

Comment: I did manage to get it to show as I wanted now. I had to adjust it a little. Thanks John

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete" + " " + statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Delete" + " " + statesListBox.SelectedItem.ToString() + "?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

Answer (score 0):

```
DialogResult dlgRes = MessageBox.Show("Delete", "Are you sure you want to delete?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

if (dlgRes == DialogResult.Yes)
{

}
```